# Single vs. a set of Random Variables

Tags: statistics, random-variables, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

Given $X=\text{the number of heads in 5 dice throws}$. Here $X$ is a "single" RV and the outcomes are mappes to some distribution.

However, i get confused when $X=\{ X_1,X_2,...,X_n \} $ is called "a sample of size $n$, or of equally distrubuted RV's. What does that mean? Could it mean:

a) something like $X_1=\text{the number of heads in 5 dice throws in exp. 1}$, $X_2=\text{the number of heads in 5 dice throws exp. 2}$ and so on

b) something like $X_1=\text{the number of heads in 5 dice throws in some exp. }$, $X_2=\text{number of people with weight x in some further exp. }$ and so on

What is the meaning of $n$ in this context: does it "measure" $n$ diferent attributes to observe or indicate just $n$ repitions of the experiment?

Comment: You are expected to read it as (a).  Here $n$ is the sample size or the number of repetitions of the experiment, i.e. the number of times there are $5$ dice throws.  (By the way, most dice do not have "heads")

Comment: Given $X=\{ X_1,X_2,...,X_n \} $ , is there a difference in the distribution of $X_i$'s and $X$ ?

Also, lets assume the first statements again: X=the number of heads in 5 dice throws (sorry for the dice with heads ): if we assume, i.e a binomial distribution, we also plot all outcomes and their probability - which is more or less the same to me as repeating the throw many times and caltuling their prop. by considering the frequency - however, i would not consider each throw a random variable in its own right? where is my mind stuck

Comment: As you say, each $X_i$ the number of successes from $5$ attempts is presumably a binomial random variable giving a single integer value from $0$ to $5$.  But $X$ is the result of this done $n$ times and so is $n$-dimensional (list, vector, array, whatever, possibly even a multiset as order is not very important in this particular case, but I would have thought $X$ is not a set as it may have repetitions)